why my render animation only render my sequencer and not the compositer
i have a clip editor using some trackers and then a video sequencer to crop and ...
in the end i have this compositer to control the transformation and color of the video
but the problem is that my render only renders the result at the sequencer lever

as you see the compositer should be black and white but still my render will be a colorful video

The Compositor cannot be used on the output of the Sequencer. If you want to perform any transformations or color adjustments you have to do it in the Sequencer.

ok seems blender considers compositor and sequencer as 2 separate postprocess tools and wont use their output in the other tool
so the workaround is something like creating a new scene
having compositor only in scene1 and sequencer in scene2
add a scene strip to sequencer and set the source to scene1
